# Repeat the header of a document for each page

Tags: header-footer

With the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\addtolength{\textheight}{4cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2.4cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1.2cm}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsen}{arcsen}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}



%-----------------------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------------------------

% AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

\begin{center}

\large{{\bf Written examination}}

\vspace{0.2cm}
%{\bf 04/02/2019 }\\[.2cm]
{\bf 31 January 2020 }\\[.2cm]
Prof. XX and Prof. YY \\[1ex]

\vspace{0.3cm}
Surname, Name, student ID ...............................................................

\end{center}

%\noindent\large{Matricola ............................................. %Anno di corso ................................}


\vspace{0.5cm}

\noindent{\bf Solve the following exercises in full, adequately justifying the procedures followed.}


\vspace{0.3cm}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

I produce the document depicted in the figure:
[image]

This page should host some exercises to be written immediately after the bold part.

My question is this. I would like to write multiple assignment templates (for example 10) in the same document, so I would need to repeat the header (the part that goes from "written examination" to the sentence starting with "Solve the following") for each new page. How can I do it in TeX?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- use package `fancyhdr` to define your header with `\fancyhead[C]{...}`
- replaced deprecated commands like `\bf` with `\textbf{...}`
- use package `geometry` to define the page margins and the header size

  - you can uncomment the option `%showframe` to see the borders
  - this also replaces those hacky `\addtolength` commands
- added package `lipsum` for testing
- removed unnecessary packages and commands

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
    %showframe,
    headsep=10mm,
    headheight=50mm,
    left=20mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=70mm,
    bottom=30mm,
]{geometry}

\frenchspacing

\fancyhead[C]{
    {
        \large
        \textbf{Written examination}\\[2mm]
        \textbf{31 January 2020}\\[2mm]
        Prof. XX and Prof. YY \\[5mm]
        Surname, Name, student ID ...............................................................\\[4mm]
    }
    \raggedright\noindent\textbf{Solve the following exercises in full, adequately justifying the procedures followed.}
    \vspace{3mm}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]